# How to do 2 column in ul tag with two elements in li

Tags: html, css

I want to in ul tag have two column, and each input should have image.
For example, previous i have this and it was good

```
.res{
    list-style-type: none;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}

<ul class="res">
    <li>
        <input type="number" step="10" min="0" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="number" step="10" min="0" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="number" step="10" min="0" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

later i added image to each li

```
<ul class="res">
    <li>
        <img src="images/item1.png" width="34px" height="34px"/>
        <input type="number" step="10" min="0" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/item2.png" width="34px" height="34px"/>
        <input type="number" step="10" min="0" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/item3.png" width="34px" height="34px"/>
        <input type="number" step="10" min="0" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

And everything goes wrong, this looks like

```
image    input
input    image
image    input
```

and i want to

```
image input    image input
image input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/1s9h6vpk/)?

I just floated all li's to this:

```
<li style="float:left;">
```

Comment: No, now everything is in one column

Comment: Its funny, in jsfiddle works fine, but not in my page.

Comment: What is the link to your page?